# How to delete an application in sandboxed App?

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I am trying to delete an application in the /Applications folder on macOS High Sierra (I don't hink the exact OS really matters).

But I simply can not figure out, how to do so from a sandboxed app. In the Mac App Store there are a couple (in fact a lot) of apps that can do that.

When an app is selected, a prompt is shown where I can type in my password.

First I tried creating a helper utility and then calling SMJobBless. But after failing I noticed that this is not possible in a sandboxed app (kinda makes sense because you could completely bypass the sandbox?).

Then I tried to write an AppleScript. This really works fine, the prompt is shown and the file is either deleted or moved to the trash.
I had to add an entitlement:

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events
```

I have added co.apple.finder as a child node and like I said everything works fine. Unfortunately, this entitlement is not allowed in the Mac App Store (again, this makes sense).

Now my question is...how can I move a file to the trash (I do not need to delete it myself, it would be okay if the user had to empty the trash manually).
How do all those other apps do it?

Comment: Register the application folder with the security-scoped bookmark.  That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can think of would be to open an NSOpenPanel, and get the user to select the application you want to delete. Not too many MAS-approved ways to poke through the sandbox beyond that.

Comment: A secure bookmark is required to read the contents of the applications folder. But (re)moving files in it requires higher privileges (admin prompt).

Comment: I just tried it; if you're logged in as an admin user and you've got a secure bookmark, you're indeed able to remove things in /Applications provided that they're owned by the current user (obviously it won't work for system-provided applications and/or anything your current user doesn't have write access to).

Comment: I am logged in as an user with admin rights. But when trying to delete a file from the Applications folder (with secure bookmark), I receive an error. Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: Yep, my app was sandboxed (and I tested it by trying to run it first with the "User Selected File" entitlement turned off, and it didn't work then).

Does your admin user have write access to the item you tried to delete?

Comment: I don't have write access, so that is the problem. But the question is...how to get that write access (temporarily). Like I said, there are a lot of available apps that do exactly that, so it must be possible? You can check the app "Delete Apps" from the mac app store as an example, it is free. Once a binary file is selected, a prompt is shown.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to prompt for the admin password that's App Store-friendly. You'd just need to be logged in under an account that has write access to the app you want to delete.

Comment: I only have one account on my machine - "my" account with admin privileges. All apps in the applications folder were installed via the Mac App Store and the user is "root". I can not log in as root.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably just have to distribute outside of the App Store.